# Using a http proxy with Apache Camel's http4 endpoint

Tags: java, apache-camel

I'm attempting to use a http proxy with Camel's http4 component. The proxy works when testing using Intellij's HTTP Proxy "Check Connection" option.

However I don't know how to configure it correctly via Camel. When running the following integration test a "ConnectException: Connection timed out" is thrown. Can anyone clarify how to set the proxy details correctly please?

```
public class SimpleHttpProxyIT extends CamelTestSupport {
    public static final String DIRECT_START = "direct:start";
    public static final String MOCK_RESULT = "mock:result";

    @Produce(uri = DIRECT_START)
    protected ProducerTemplate basic;

    @EndpointInject(uri = MOCK_RESULT)
    protected MockEndpoint resultEndpoint;

    @Test
    public void testBasic() throws Exception {
        basic.sendBody(null);
        resultEndpoint.setExpectedMessageCount(1);
        resultEndpoint.assertIsSatisfied();
    }

    @Override
    public RouteBuilder createRouteBuilder() throws Exception {

        return new RouteBuilder() {
            @Override
            public void configure() throws Exception {
                from(DIRECT_START)
                        .id("SunriseTest")
                        .log(LoggingLevel.INFO, "About to hit sunrise")
                        .setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_URI, simple("http://api.sunrise-sunset.org/json?lat=36.7201600&lng=-4.4203400"))
                        .process(new Processor() {
                            @Override
                            public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
                                exchange.getProperties().put("http.proxyAuthHost", "myproxy.company.org");
                                exchange.getProperties().put("http.proxyAuthPort", "10000");
                                exchange.getProperties().put("http.proxyAuthMethod", "Basic");
                                exchange.getProperties().put("http.proxyAuthUsername", "myusername");
                                exchange.getProperties().put("http.proxyAuthPassword", "mypassword");
                            }
                        })
                       .recipientList(simple("http4:dummyhost"))
                        .log(LoggingLevel.INFO, "Done")
                        .to(MOCK_RESULT);
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would think it should should be `exchange.setProperty(...)`

Answer (score 0):

Setting the properties in the URI worked. I misread the documentation on "Using Proxy Settings Outside of the URI" (http://camel.apache.org/http4.html) as this was referring to setting them on the **context**, not the **exchange**.

```
public class SimpleHttpProxyIT extends CamelTestSupport {
    public static final String DIRECT_START = "direct:start";
    public static final String MOCK_RESULT = "mock:result";

    @Produce(uri = DIRECT_START)
    protected ProducerTemplate basic;

    @EndpointInject(uri = MOCK_RESULT)
    protected MockEndpoint resultEndpoint;

    @Test
    public void testBasic() throws Exception {
        basic.sendBody(null);
        resultEndpoint.setExpectedMessageCount(1);
        resultEndpoint.assertIsSatisfied();
    }

    @Override
    public RouteBuilder createRouteBuilder() throws Exception {

        return new RouteBuilder() {
            @Override
            public void configure() throws Exception {
                from(DIRECT_START)
                        .id("SunriseTest")
                        .log(LoggingLevel.INFO, "About to hit sunrise")
                        .setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_URI, simple("http://api.sunrise-sunset.org/json?lat=36.7201600&lng=-4.4203400"))
                       .recipientList(simple("http4:dummyhost?proxyAuthHost=myproxy.company.org&proxyAuthPort=10000&proxyAuthUsername=myusername&proxyAuthPassword=mypassword"))
                        .log(LoggingLevel.INFO, "Done")
                        .to(MOCK_RESULT);
            }
        };
    }
}
```